# Deleted google font link but the font still work

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts

I have deleted the google font **link** tag from my website development, but does the font still work?
Could the browser depend on the system to get the font if I used it for ( font-family )?

Comment: Are you sure you are not just looking at a cached version? If the `font-family` rule was removed, then the font should be changed back to the default value.

Comment: Maybe you have the font installed locally? I sometimes install them when I’m doing the initial design work.

Comment: Yes that is my question, i searched but did not find any prove .. i have this font loaclly

Comment: I cleared the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it and disabled the font on my mac, and i found that the source was  the mac system font .. it seems like the browser uses the local font if it found it .